# Complex SQL Query with group by Clause

Tags: sql, group-by

I am not an sql expert but I have got this query

```
USE msdb
DECLARE
    @JobStepCount int,
@JobName sysname,
@JobID uniqueidentifier

DECLARE @JobStatus TABLE (JobStatusID int, JobStatus varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @JobStatus (JobStatusID, JobStatus)
VALUES (0, 'Failed'),
    (1, 'Succeeded'),
(2, 'Retry'),
    (3, 'Cancelled')

SET @JobName = 'Expedient BookingRefresh'

SELECT
    @JobID = job_id
FROM
    sysjobs j
where
j.name = @JobName

SELECT
@JobStepCount = COUNT(*)
FROM
dbo.sysjobsteps
WHERE
job_id = @JobID

SELECT
RunDate,
RunTime,
RunDuration,
JobStatus
FROM
(   SELECT
    jstart.instance_id,
    RunDate,
    RunTime,
    RunDuration,
    MIN(h.run_status) as run_status
FROM
    sysjobhistory h
inner join
(
    SELECT
        instance_id,
        jstart.instance_id - @JobStepCount  AS instance_range,
        jstart.run_date AS RunDate,
        CONVERT(time, LEFT(jstart.run_time, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(jstart.run_time, 3,     2) + ':' + RIGHT(jstart.run_time, 2)) AS RunTime,
        CONVERT(time, LEFT(jstart.run_duration, 2) + ':' +      SUBSTRING(jstart.run_duration, 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(jstart.run_duration, 2)) AS RunDuration
    FROM
    (   SELECT
            instance_id,
            CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_date), 112) AS run_date,
            RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), run_time), 6) AS run_time,
            RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), run_duration), 6) AS run_duration
        FROM
            sysjobhistory hstart
        WHERE
            step_id = 0
        AND
            job_id = @JobID
    ) jstart
) jstart
    on
        h.instance_id between jstart.instance_range and jstart.instance_id
    AND
        h.job_id = @JobID
    GROUP BY
        jstart.instance_id,
        RunDate,
        RunTime,
            RunDuration
) a    
INNER JOIN
    @JobStatus js
ON
    js.JobStatusID = a.run_status

ORDER BY
    RunDate, RunTime
```

I get the result like the one below:

```
2013-05-09  02:15:44.0000000    00:14:46.0000000    Succeeded
2013-05-09  02:56:17.0000000    23:18:25.0000000    Succeeded
2013-05-10  06:00:00.0000000    01:56:18.0000000    Cancelled
```

I am looking for a result like this:

```
        Date         Number of runs         Success Count            Failure/Cancel Count   
        2013-05-09      2                    2                      0   
        2013-05-10      1                    0                      1
```

I tried some combinations to sum up the date and want able to get the result in the desired format. Can someone help me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try like this...

```
SELECT
cAST(RunDate AS dATE),
Count(*) as Number_of_Run,
Sum(Case When JobStatus='Succeeded' then 1 else 0 end) as Success_Count,   
Sum(Case When JobStatus='Cancelled' or JobStatus='Failure' then 1 else 0 end) as FailureCancelCount  
FROM --I M USING THE tABLE wHICH you mentioned in your question......
(SELECT
RunDate,
RunTime,
RunDuration,
JobStatus
FROM
(   SELECT
    jstart.instance_id,
    RunDate,
    RunTime,
    RunDuration,
    MIN(h.run_status) as run_status
FROM
    sysjobhistory h
inner join
(
    SELECT
        instance_id,
        jstart.instance_id - @JobStepCount  AS instance_range,
        jstart.run_date AS RunDate,
        CONVERT(time, LEFT(jstart.run_time, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(jstart.run_time, 3,     2) + ':' + RIGHT(jstart.run_time, 2)) AS RunTime,
        CONVERT(time, LEFT(jstart.run_duration, 2) + ':' +      SUBSTRING(jstart.run_duration, 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(jstart.run_duration, 2)) AS RunDuration
    FROM
    (   SELECT
            instance_id,
            CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), run_date), 112) AS run_date,
            RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), run_time), 6) AS run_time,
            RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), run_duration), 6) AS run_duration
        FROM
            sysjobhistory hstart
        WHERE
            step_id = 0
        AND
            job_id = @JobID
    ) jstart
) jstart
    on
        h.instance_id between jstart.instance_range and jstart.instance_id
    AND
        h.job_id = @JobID
    GROUP BY
        jstart.instance_id,
        RunDate,
        RunTime,
            RunDuration
) a    
INNER JOIN
    @JobStatus js
ON
    js.JobStatusID = a.run_status

ORDER BY
    RunDate, RunTime) t
            group by RunDate
            ORDER BY RunDate
```

Comment: Hi Amit , I just ran the query and it did not return any result.

Comment: @BhaskarMishra if you are geting the table as you mentioned ..in question than it shuld work..see here....http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f559b/4

Comment: Hey Amit, I did not mention the table structure if you see there are lot of joins to fetch data . Its not a simple table where we the data to sum it up.

Comment: @BhaskarMishra when you run your query....you get the table as you show in question??

Comment: @BhaskarMishra.....try now....i used your table which you said you get it when you run your query....

Comment: @BhaskarMishra you are getting the same table as you mention in your question when you run your query

Comment: Can we move this to chat? i cant chat here as I dont have enough points. bhaskar.mishra@gmail.com is my id.. let me know

Comment: i m in offficwe i can not chat.....but i m dead sure if your geting table like  you said in your question it shuld always..i dont know why  its not working in your case